# In landscape mode, can't add lines or boxes wider than 8"

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

In Crystal Reports 2008, to which I've recently upgraded, I have a new report in which I'm trying to place boxes and lines. The report is Letter, landscape, with .25" margins, so I have 10.5" of space to work with.

Unfortunately, Crystal will only let me place drawing objects in the first 8" of space. If they overlap that range, Crystal sizes them back to 8". If I place them entirely to the right, Crystal moves them back to the 8" mark.

I have the same problem if I try to change the width or position using the **Size and Position** box.

Sounds like a bug where it's mistaking the available length for the available width.

Any idea how to fix this or work around it?

Comment: This is just a guess, but have you tried disabling 'Snap to Grid'? Regardless of the paper size, you should be able to drag drawing objects _outside_ of the printable area.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, **Snap to Grid** is turned off.

Comment: Outside the printable area – hmm. I wonder if there's an option I need to set. Or is that new in CR 2008? CR XI didn't like let me move items outside the printable area, I don't think, and sometimes acted strangely if I shrunk the printable area while text fields etc. were sitting outside.

Comment: Just tried it. I can pull fields off the margins except for drawing objects. If I shrink the page size, the size of the drawing objects don't change, they just aren't visible, but they're still there outside of the margins. http://i.imgur.com/yr7hZ.png Is this also the case with CR for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old thread i know but here is the correct answer/fix.

The issue with only being able to draw a line so far across the report is due the the ruler at the top not extending along the full length of the report page.

This in turn is down to the default printer that is selected and the restricted paper sizes that it allows.

Install a dummy printer that accepts larger paper sizes and either set it to default, or click on File > Page Setup and under printer options, select the dummy printer.

The ruler should now extend across the full length of the report page and you can extend your line to match it.

NB: This was in Crystal Reports 2013 R2 - The settings may differ slightly in older/newer versions.

Comment: How does one install a dummy printer?

Comment: Start > Devices and Printers > Add Printer.  Just pick a generic printer that allows A3 printing and that should cover it.  Something like a Konica Minolta C353.  It doesn't have to be default, it can just be installed on the PC and left unused, providing you make the change in the above fix where you go to File > Page Setup in Crystal Reports.

Comment: Awesome. I'm sure this will help out a couple people!

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue. could not scratch lines. 
i tried to change page setup from landscape to portrait and then did required changes. 
again changed page setup to landscape and it was working fine .